# Soldering wire directly to a PCB through hole vias, what is acceptable proximity tolerance?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, wire, pcb-assembly, via

The wire gauge is 16 AWG. The hole size is 63 mil, and the overall via diameter is 98.5 mil.

What is the minimum spacing between two of these for voltage levels of 0-12V and 0-160V circuits?

I think I can get away with 150 mils between centers and solder wires ok and bend the wires ok as well.

Comment: Is this something you're making one of, or is it something you're going to put into production?   If it's going into production, and somebody else will be soldering, I'd give as much clearance as your design possibly allows.  Don't underestimate factory workers ability to screw up soldering.   You can also effectively increase the distance by milling a slot between the pads.

Comment: thanks for the ipc-221a chart that helps

Comment: was mainly worried about voltage clearances (but not anymore looking at the chart) 
 and assembly: if the vias are too close then the assembler wouldn't be able to solder the 16awg wires to them well enough. I should be ok with 180 mils between centers of vias. thanks for all the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a table from [IPC-2221A](http://www-eng.lbl.gov/%7Eshuman/NEXT/CURRENT_DESIGN/TP/MATERIALS/IPC-2221A(L).pdf) but it's not the latest version: -

[image]

You should aim to check the latest version and apply suitable extra dimensioning to be more secure. For more information on IPC see [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPC_(electronics)).

Answer (score 0):

The cleareance depends on whether you circuit is considered a "primary circuit" (the mains) or a "secondary circuit" (SELV).

You should refer to norm UL 60950 or IEC 60950.

There's a short excerpt of that norm around, available at Texas Instruments website, that will help you.

Google this: "Clearance and creepage_UL-60950_IEC-60950.pdf"

---

Use a pollution degree of 2 in your calculations.

You will end up with a clearance less than 2.4 mm.

Pollution degree 3 is meant for products working in dusty or very humid environments.

---

Back in 2017, when I UL certified a 50 Watt PSU in Europe (mains 230 Vrms) I had a clearance of 2.4 mm between LINE and NEUTRAL.