# Typical filled zone clearance

Tags: clearance

What are typical clearance settings for a filled zone (GND) on a PCB with 3.3V and 12V voltages? Is 0.25mm enough?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595607/soldering-wire-directly-to-a-pcb-through-hole-vias-what-is-acceptable-proximity/595619#595619

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the capabilities of your PCB vendor for minimum spaces, and chances are that 0.25mm is considered acceptable, however using something like 0.5mm (20 mils) specifically for clearance to pours will make the board more manufacturable and less prone to assembly shorts.

One set of rules I've used is 20mils (~0.5mm) general polygon clearances and 40 mils (~1mm) to mounting holes with suppliers who have no problem with 0.2mm clearances.

[image]